# How to apply different importance to different features in linear regressio

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, predictive-models, fitting

I am fitting a linear regression model. I want to apply different importance/priority to different predictive features in the data. Like some of the features are more important than others. How do we incorporate this different importance of features ??

Answer (score 3):

The only way to accomplish this is through constraints on coefficients. This will not be a standard linear regression though. It'll be similar to [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) except the shrinkage coefficient will be a vector, not scalar.

For instance, you define a problem as a typical least squares with a penalty on coefficients:
$$\min_{\beta_j} \sum_i(y_i-\beta_0-\sum_{j=1}^k x_{ij}\beta_j)^2+\sum_{j=1}^k\frac 1 {\lambda_j}\beta_j^2$$
Here, $\lambda_j$ are the regularization weights. Higher weight means more important feature.

Comment: I do believe this to be the correct answer, so +1. However, am I crazy to think this feels like cheating? Even a regular shrinkage coefficient in ridge or lasso regression would be tuned by cross validation and, therefore, be learned from the data instead of specified.

Comment: @Dave, I think the idea's that the importance is not tuned but given by OP.

Comment: @Dave In fact it's not uncommon to set the penalty term as $\phi \sum_{j=1}^k\frac 1 {\lambda_j}\beta_j^2$ & tune $\phi$ by cross validation - to penalize coefficients representing nonlinearity or interaction more strongly, say.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, linear regression is a "data driven" approach (in stead of "knowledge driven"). This means the data will tell you which variable is important, and how much are they important (in terms of p-value etc.).

To best of my knowledge, we do not have a good way to tell model which one should be used or not, other than excluding that variable in the model.

---

I am not very familiar with Bayesian approach, but I think One way of doing it is set the prior of $\beta$ for the knowledge driven variable importance?

Comment: i was trying to to analyse the data manually, see which feature is important and then maybe doubling the weight corresponding to that feature while training.

Comment: : |  That's not what p-values measure.

Comment: You're not allowed to vote twice for the same candidate. (The analogy isn't perfect, as you *can* vote for several different candidates.) Seriously, weights can be applied to observations. In what sense do you think they can be applied to predictors?

Comment: @MatthewDrury can you help me with p-value? can I understand it as the probability of given predictor is significant / important?

Comment: No, it's not that (well, unless you take the word "important" to mean the below, since "important" is an undefined term).  The p-value is the conditional probability of observing a parameter *estimate* equally or more extreme than the estimate actually found, conditional on the assumption that the *true parameter* is zero.

Comment: @MatthewDrury thanks for educating me. So can I say, suppose "true" parameter is 1e-6, and p-value is 2e-16. it is significant but not "important", since the impact of magnitude is too small?

Comment: I duno, it depends on what you take the meaning of "important" to be.  What you're basically doing when you say that is defining important to mean "coefficient is small".  Maybe that makes sense for your application.  But "important predictor" doesn't mean anything statistically.